# force same block layout in dask arrays of identical shape and differing datatypes

Tags: python, dask

I have large dask workflow which produces two different arrays with identical shapes but differing blocks (and data types). I tried re-chunking each of these arrays (with the same block size) but since they have different data types the blocks are different.  Is there a way that I can force each of these arrays to have the same block geometry so that I can use map array functions more easily (specifically I have to design a map_blocks function that iterates over two input dask arrays at the same time and having identical blocks would make this substantially easier to do)? This is a simplified example that recreates the problem:

```
import dask.array as da 
import numpy as np
arrayOne  = da.random.random((96700000000), chunks=(96700000000))
arrayTwo = arrayOne >= 5
#they are the same
print(arrayOne.numblocks)
print(arrayTwo.numblocks)
#now rechunk to screw this up
arrayOne = arrayOne.rechunk({0: -1, 0: 'auto'},block_size_limit=1e6)
arrayTwo = arrayTwo.rechunk({0: -1, 0: 'auto'},block_size_limit=1e6)
print(arrayOne.numblocks)
print(arrayTwo.numblocks)
```

This code outputs: (1,)(1,) and (773600,),(96700,)
Edit:
One super hacky way to fix this is by using the size of the underlying data, but I assume there must be a better approach?

```
arrayOne = arrayOne.rechunk({0: -1, 0: 'auto'},block_size_limit=1e6)
arrayTwo = arrayTwo.rechunk({0: -1, 0: 'auto'},block_size_limit=1e6/np.dtype(arrayOne.dtype).itemsize)
```

Now is there anything that I can do to force each of these arrays to have the same number of blocks?

Thank You, any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `"auto"` here in chunking chooses chunk sizes of a certain memory size.  It's probably not what you want.

Instead, you might consider rechunking one array to use the other's chunk structure.

```
x = x.rechunk(y.chunks)
```

I would also have expected `da.map_blocks` to handle the rechunking for you.

Comment: Thank You, I did not realize that it was that simple!